# Custom Scheduled Tasks in Win11 causing PowerShell & CMD.exe pop-ups - how to make them silent / background tasks?

Tags: command-line, powershell, scheduled-tasks

How can I make these run silently in the background?

Here is my PowerShell script:

```
rm C:\*.jpg
rm C:\*.doc
rm C:\*.pptx
rm C:\*.xls

rm C:\Users\*.jpg
rm C:\Users\*.doc
rm C:\Users\*.pptx
rm C:\Users\*.xls

# set var for username
$yourUser = $env:USERNAME 

rm C:\users\$yourUser\*.jpg
rm c:\users\$yourUser\*.doc
rm c:\users\$yourUser\*.pptx
rm c:\users\$yourUser\*.xls
```

And, if needed, here is the XML for the PS Script (Scheduled Task exported):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2022-06-23T15:11:00.2977928</Date>
    <Author>MyDomain\MyUser</Author>
    <Description>Nuke annoying AV junk files</Description>
    <URI>\PS_Nuke_Annoying_files.ps1</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2022-06-23T15:08:58</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-12-1-679272179-1229781794-976310157-3256474971</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Temp\PS_Nuke_annoying_files.ps1</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Edit your Scheduled Task `Action`.  Change `Program/script` to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  Change `Add arguments (optional)` to `-NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -File C:\Temp\PS_Nuke_annoying_files.ps1`

Comment: Thank you, @leeharvey1. Unfortunately I'm still getting the pop-up. Any other ideas?

Comment: Change your Scheduled Task to run in the `SYSTEM` context, then either hard-code your `$yourUser` variable to a known user account string, or (more dangerous), add `-Recurse` to the end of `rm C:\Users` (Remove-Item) lines to impact all C:\Users folders and sub-folders.  Optionally, add `-Confirm:$false -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` at the end of each `rm` (Remove-Item) line, to ensure you are never prompted.

Comment: Yes, that worked!! Thank you! Please post the answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid seeing the PowerShell command window pop-up from a Scheduled Task:

- Change your Scheduled Task account to run in the `SYSTEM` context, then either hard-code your `$yourUser` variable to a known user account string; or (*more dangerously*), add `-Recurse` to the end of `rm C:\Users` (Remove-Item) lines in your script to impact all C:\Users folders and sub-folders.
- Edit your Scheduled Task **Action**. Change *Program/script* to
  `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. Change
  *Add arguments (optional)* to `-NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -File C:\Temp\PS_Nuke_annoying_files.ps1`
- Optionally, add `-Confirm:$false -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` at the end of each rm (Remove-Item) line in your script, to ensure you are never prompted.